# How to force open an excel file with appropriate app in Swift in my iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, excel

I succeeded to make an excel file by using **libXlsxWriter** in Swift in my App and I have an URL that represent the excel file.

I made Share button for users to share the excel file easily by using **UIDocumentInteractionController**. 
[image]

Now I want to add an Open button for users to open the excel file easily with appropriate app such as **Microsoft Excel** and **Polaris Office** in my App. 
(I know that I can select Polaris Office and Microsoft Excel when I clicked share button but the other share methods are also shown. I want to force open excel app)

However I couldn't find a solution.
How can I force to open excel file with appropriate apps from URL in Swift?
Is it possible?